# AS3 ExternalInterface call using jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm calling into a flash app embedded in a html page using the ExternalInterface.
The following code works fine (I'm using a button to test):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var app = document.getElementById('ApplicationID')
        console.debug(app)
        app.pageUnloading()
    })
})
```

So this calls into the flash app fine and prints:

```
<embed id="ApplicationID" width="600" height="400" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="FlexMoeders" bgcolor="#cccccc" quality="high" src="ApplicationID.swf">
```

But when I use the jquery $# method of getting an element by id, I receive a different object back:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var app = $("#ApplicationID")
        console.debug(app)
        app.pageUnloading()
    })
})
```

When I use this I'm told:

```
app.pageUnloaded is not a function
```

and the following is printed:

```
[embed#ApplicationID]
```

I have also tried:

```
var app = $("#ApplicationID").val()

var app = $("#ApplicationID").get(0)
```

But still no success. Does anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Do you have a sample page to show this off? `.get(0)` works for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var app = $('#ApplicationID')[0]
```

or

```
var app = $('#ApplicationID').get(0)
```

should do the same thing as

```
var app = document.getElementById('ApplicationID')
```

Comment: my bad with the .get(0), it does work, but I was calling the wrong function

Answer (score 5):

When you use `$("#ApplicationID")` you will get back a jQuery object.

That's why it doesn't work. But `$("#ApplicationID").get(0)` actually should work.